# Multiple service instances are getting started using tomcat although port is busy with the first instance

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat, sh, tomcat6

I have a shell script to run an application for which I am using Tomcat 6.39. Issue is that when I run the script application starts even though the application is already running on the same port.

P.S. I do encounter port is busy message, but after that tomcat continues to load service start packages and starts it.

How can I resolve this issue?

Below are the tomcat logs for the same:

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Mar 22, 2018 7:21:09 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed) <null>:9894
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:549)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:703)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:838)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
        ... 12 more

Mar 22, 2018 7:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initialize
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9894]]
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed) <null>:9894
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:703)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:838)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)


Mar 22, 2018 7:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 577 ms
Mar 22, 2018 7:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 22, 2018 7:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.39
Mar 22, 2018 7:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Mar 22, 2018 7:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Mar 22, 2018 7:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive rp.war
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxRollFileCount] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxRollFileCount] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxRollFileCount] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Tomcat behaves, because being not able to start a Server Socket is not fatal and the bindings don't come first during the startup.

It will not stop starting and exit because a port is already busy with another Tomcat. It's up to you to know when to start (when all conditions are gathered : enough free memory, enough disk space for the logs, nothing already binding on the coveted ports).

Comment: How can I avoid this?

Comment: You can write a startup script that will do the necessary checks.

Comment: Yeah I have put a check in my script for status of the application, works just fine. Thanks for clarification